# SQL Выборка строк с нарушением

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите в каком направлении думать. Есть таблица, такого типа:

```
create table table1(
  Id int primary key,
  User nvarchar(30),
  Typeofposition nvarchar(60),
  PayDate date,
  Price  numeric(15,2) );

insert into table(
  Id,
  User,
  Typeofposition,
  PayDate,
  Price )
 ( 1, 'user1', 'Взнос', '20120216', 1000 ),
 ( 2, 'user1', 'использование', '20120216', 0 ),
 ( 3, 'user1', 'использование', '20120215', 1000 ),
 ( 4, 'user2', 'использование', '20120220', 0 ),
 ( 5, 'user2', 'использование', '20120223', 300 ),
 ( 6, 'user2', 'Взнос', '20120321', 1000 ),
 ( 7, 'user3', 'использование', '20120521', 0 ),
 ( 8, 'user1', 'использование', '20151015', 0 )
```

По правилам, сервисом можно пользоваться двумя способами.

1) Либо сразу взносишь 1000 руб и можешь пользоваться сервисом бесплатно в течении 4 месяцев (заказ записывается в БД с ценой 0);

2)При каждом использовании оплачиваешь услугу

написать SQL-запрос, который вернет из таблицы `table`  позиции «активность», оформленные с нарушениями. Так, в приведенной выше таблице нарушены позиции :

```
Id = 4 - "использование" с ценой 0 проведен раньше "взноса";
Id = 7 - "использование" с ценой 0 проведен без оплаты "взноса";
Id = 8 - "использование" с ценой 0 проведено спустя более 4 месяцев после оплаты "взноса".
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table(
  Id int primary key,
  User nvarchar(30),
  Typeofposition nvarchar(60),' at line 1

Comment: исправил table на table1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Вариант 1.  Курсор

Можно отсортировать данные по пользователю и дате. Завести табличную переменную, где будем хранить нарушения, аналогичную по структуре исходной таблице.

Открыть по запросу курсор и по каждому пользователю при каждом взносе запоминать `PayDate` в переменную `@last_pay_date`, а для использований с нулевой стоимостью считать `datediff` от последней запомненной даты.

Для использований: если `datediff` превышает 4 месяца или `@last_pay_date is null` - добавлять строку в табличную переменную.

При переходе к следующему пользователю - обнулять `@last_pay_date`.

В конце - вернуть содержимое.

```
declare @violations table(
  Id int,
  [User] nvarchar(30),
  Typeofposition nvarchar(60),
  PayDate date,
  Price numeric(15,2))

declare 
  @cur_id int,
  @cur_user nvarchar(30),
  @prev_user nvarchar(30),
  @cur_type nvarchar(60),
  @cur_date date,
  @cur_price numeric(15,2),
  @last_pay_date date

DECLARE cur CURSOR 
FOR 
  SELECT Id, [User], Typeofposition, PayDate, Price 
  FROM table1 
  WHERE Typeofposition = N'Взнос' OR Price = 0
  ORDER BY [User], PayDate

OPEN cur

FETCH NEXT FROM cur 
INTO @cur_id, @cur_user, @cur_type, @cur_date, @cur_price

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 BEGIN
  IF @cur_user <> @prev_user OR @prev_user IS NULL BEGIN
    SET @last_pay_date = null
    SET @prev_user = @cur_user
  END

  IF @cur_type = N'Взнос'
    SET @last_pay_date = @cur_date
  ELSE BEGIN 
    IF @last_pay_date IS NULL OR datediff(month, @last_pay_date, @cur_date) > 4
      INSERT INTO @violations
      VALUES (@cur_id, @cur_user, @cur_type, @cur_date, @cur_price)
  END  

  FETCH NEXT FROM cur 
  INTO @cur_id, @cur_user, @cur_type, @cur_date, @cur_price
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur

SELECT * FROM @violations
```

Пример на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5d312/40)

---

### Вариант 2. [Оконная функция](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189461(v=sql.120).aspx)

Оконные функции позволяют вычислить некоторое агрегатное значение для каждой строки, опираясь на некоторые диапазоны строк, относительно текущей, или секции (похожие на группы в `GROUP BY`).

Рассмотрим поэтапно:

1. Сортируем по пользователю и дате. Отбрасываем использования с ненулевой оплатой.

   ```
   SELECT
     * 
   FROM table1
   WHERE Typeofposition = N'Взнос' OR Price = 0
   ORDER BY [User], PayDate
   ```
2. Разбиваем на секции по пользователю с сортировкой по дате. Для каждой секции вычисляем максимальную скользящую дату внесения платежа (максимальную дату с начала секции и до текущей строки). Для "взносов" - это `PayDate`, для использований - `null`.

   ```
   SELECT
     * ,
     MAX(
       CASE Typeofposition WHEN N'Взнос' THEN PayDate ELSE null END
     ) OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY PayDate) as LastPayDate,
   FROM table1
   WHERE Typeofposition = N'Взнос' OR Price = 0
   ORDER BY [User], PayDate
   ```
3. Вычисляем `datediff` в месяцах между `PayDate` и максимальной скользящей датой внесения платежа.

   ```
   SELECT
     * ,
     datediff(month, MAX(
       CASE Typeofposition WHEN N'Взнос' THEN PayDate ELSE null END
     ) OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY PayDate), PayDate) as MonthsSinceLastPayment

   FROM table1
   WHERE Typeofposition = N'Взнос' OR Price = 0
   ORDER BY [User], PayDate
   ```
4. `OVER`-выражения нельзя использовать в `WHERE`, поэтому обернем все в `SELECT` и выберем строки, где MonthsSinceLastPayment не задан (взносов еще не было) или превышает 4 месяца:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT
     * ,
     datediff(month, MAX(
       CASE Typeofposition WHEN N'Взнос' THEN PayDate ELSE null END
     ) OVER (PARTITION BY [User] ORDER BY PayDate), PayDate) as MonthsSinceLastPayment

   FROM table1
   WHERE Typeofposition = N'Взнос' OR Price = 0
   ) Violations
   WHERE MonthsSinceLastPayment >= 4 OR MonthsSinceLastPayment IS NULL
   ```

Пример на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e5d312/1)

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас буду разбираться:)